# React table rows not changing colour. Styles are passed in, but return as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, javascript-objects

Green Dev here: I'm trying to conditionally change the row color in a react table and the styles are passed in but return as undefined. When I remove my logic and simply set backgroundColor: "red", it passes. However, the background color doesn't actually change in the app.

> ````
>    <Table
>    columns={columnData}
>    data={[...data]}
>    divided
>    getRowProps={(row) => ({
>      style: {
>        backgroundColor: rowColors[row.values.approval.ad?.status],
>      },
>    })}
>  />```
> ````

I can't figure out why the background color won't change. Once I can, I can try to set backgroundColor: "red" again and see if it changes colour. If it works, then I know that my logic is the issue and can go from there.

Here's the console output: [Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAldS.png)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does Row has the expected values?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code didn't throw an exception accessing `row.values.approval.ad?.status`, we know that `row`, `values` and `approval` are objects and not undefined. This leaves either `ad` or `status` as undefined. Considering you used `ad?.` syntax you expect ad to be undefined at least sometimes.

Add a `console.log(row.values.approval)` or simply `console.log(row)` to your render function and check which values are missing. Your problem is most likely somewhere else.

If you think the error *is indeed* in the snipped you showed, then try to specify a constant color, like this: `backgroundColor: "red"`. If the row is red, you know the error is with what I suggested first.

Comment: I can't upvote you due to lack of reputation but I'm grateful for your direction. With a constant color, console denotes a backgroundColor: "red". However, the row in the app does not change color. In terms of the conditional colours, nothing is being output in my console.log, so I think there may be an issue with row.values.approval.ad?.status. I'll update soon.